# No "different page" icon next to Privileges link on profile page

Tags: bug, design, profile-page

Here's the [user profile settings page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/email/digests/current):

> [image: Settings menu]

Since the [Privileges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) link (at the very bottom) refers to the page outside the profile page (the left menu will disappear) then the icon "different page" (same as next to "Question subscriptions") should be there.

BTW: the icon next to "Question subscriptions" looks very close to the text.

Comment: I've usually associated that icon as denoting the link takes you to a *different site* rather than a *different part of a site*.  What I mean is, "Question subscriptions" takes you to a stackexchange.com subpage, while privileges is still within the respective site you clicked on it from.  But I am no UX expert...